# wrong match in regex filter

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following sentence

```
altered carbon is the best tv show at the moment
```

and I have a filter that searches for reserved words in SQL. The next

```
@"(INNER|LEFT|JOIN|SELECT|FROM|RIGHT|DROP|ALTER|CREATE|GRANT|\*|;)";
```

But this returns to me that it has found the text **ALTER**, and I want it to return only when it finds the word ALTER, not a string that may contain ALTERed.

How do I make the words I search for be atomic, that it only finds SELECT, or FROM , or RIGHT?

Comment: Perhaps enhance the question with the actual c# code where you use it against that string

Comment: ``@"\b(?:INNER|LEFT|JOIN|SELECT|FROM|RIGHT|DROP|ALTER|CREATE|GRANT)\b|[*;]"``

Comment: What if the sentence is "This show will alter your perception of aging." If you're trying to prevent SQL injection, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: If you are trying to sanitise SQL keywords from a string, you've already lost. Use proper prepared queries and you won't have this problem.